# React Apollo networkInterface afterware doesn't handle error response

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

This is my code:

```
export const networkInterface = createNetworkInterface({
  uri: API_URL
});
networkInterface.useAfter([{


async applyAfterware({ response }, next) {
    let resCloned = response.clone();

    if (resCloned.status === 401) {
      // handle 401 error
    }
    next();
  }
}]);
```

But when the network return the response with 401, seems like the afterware not work. I receive the error in console: `POST https://myhost.com 401`

Comment: You might struggle with answers here as `createNetworkInterface` has been removed: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2458.

Comment: I  don't think so, because  I'm using old version. I don't get the syntax error. :D

Comment: Sorry, all I meant was that I'd guess the majority of people are using the latest version of Apollo now so you might not have many people answer :) From looking at examples in the upgrade documentation, I'd guess this would be due to the `async` tag you've added to your `applyAfterware`. By declaring `async`, you're wrapping the result of your `applyAfterware` in a promise which might be tripping Apollo up.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, I tried it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Upgrading can take some time and effort, but unless you're working with production code, it's probably worth it. I think there were a number of issues with the way middleware/afterware worked that were effectively fixed by introducing apollo-link.

Comment: That said, are you saying the afterware "doesn't work" because of the error you're seeing in the console... or because the code in the afterware is not being run? If you add a `console.log` inside the afterware, do you see it show up?

Comment: It's weird, really weird. If I comment the `next()`, it won't continue the process, but if I put the `debugger;` in front of `next()`, it seems like not stop there when I got the 401.